# Can't access my springboot application on GCP cluster (deployed using helm and K8s)

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-helm

So, I have deployed a sample spring boot web app, just a controller with default endpoint printing hello world . I have used helm chart to install it into a GCP Kubernetes cluster and it is supposed to be running on 8080 , even  created a load balancer service to access it as an external ip , still can't access the url , the deployment , the pod and the load balancer service are all running fine. Can you please help me with what I am missing here ?

[image]

Deployment yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1 kind: Deployment metadata: annotations: deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: "1" meta.helm.sh/release-name: demo meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: springboot-demoweb creationTimestamp: "2022-07-15T09:20:05Z" generation: 1 labels: app: springboot-demoweb app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm chart: springboot-demoweb-0.1.0 heritage: Helm release: demo name: demo-springboot-demoweb namespace: springboot-demoweb resourceVersion: "514983" uid: c0381302-7f1d-44c2-a763-fc4a743395fd spec: progressDeadlineSeconds: 600 replicas: 1 revisionHistoryLimit: 10 selector: matchLabels: app: springboot-demoweb strategy: rollingUpdate: maxSurge: 25% maxUnavailable: 25% type: RollingUpdate template: metadata: creationTimestamp: null labels: app: springboot-demoweb release: demo spec: containers: - image: rohit2502/springboot-helm-chart:latest imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent livenessProbe: failureThreshold: 3 httpGet: path: / port: 8080 scheme: HTTP periodSeconds: 10 successThreshold: 1 timeoutSeconds: 1 name: springboot-demoweb ports: - containerPort: 8080 protocol: TCP readinessProbe: failureThreshold: 3 httpGet: path: / port: 8080 scheme: HTTP periodSeconds: 10 successThreshold: 1 timeoutSeconds: 1 resources: {} terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log terminationMessagePolicy: File dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst restartPolicy: Always schedulerName: default-scheduler securityContext: {} terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30 status: availableReplicas: 1 conditions: - lastTransitionTime: "2022-07-15T09:20:25Z" lastUpdateTime: "2022-07-15T09:20:25Z" message: Deployment has minimum availability. reason: MinimumReplicasAvailable status: "True" type: Available - lastTransitionTime: "2022-07-15T09:20:05Z" lastUpdateTime: "2022-07-15T09:20:25Z" message: ReplicaSet "demo-springboot-demoweb-7dc46847bc" has successfully progressed. reason: NewReplicaSetAvailable status: "True" type: Progressing observedGeneration: 1 readyReplicas: 1 replicas: 1 updatedReplicas: 1
```

Service yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    cloud.google.com/neg: '{"ingress":true}'
  creationTimestamp: "2022-07-15T09:37:43Z"
  finalizers:
  - service.kubernetes.io/load-balancer-cleanup
  labels:
    app: springboot-demoweb
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    chart: springboot-demoweb-0.1.0
    heritage: Helm
    release: demo
  name: demo-springboot-demoweb-service
  namespace: springboot-demoweb
  resourceVersion: "544118"
  uid: 72e80300-b107-4329-852b-a3592456225d
spec:
  allocateLoadBalancerNodePorts: true
  clusterIP: 10.8.4.82
  clusterIPs:
  - 10.8.4.82
  externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  internalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  ipFamilies:
  - IPv4
  ipFamilyPolicy: SingleStack
  ports:
  - nodePort: 31905
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app: springboot-demoweb
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: LoadBalancer
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
    - ip: 104.197.133.49
```

Comment: share yaml config file for more details, or else yaml output from cluster for service and deployment. load balancer opening port 80 while sprint boot running on 8080 so hope you have mentioned the target port in service.

Comment: @HarshManvar added the yaml as suggested .

Comment: thanks,for sharing the files, it's up & running check now

Comment: Yes, thank you , it indeed is , I just had to redeploy the load balancer service again , just out of curiosity though , if my context path had say v1 in int , do I need to mention that in my lad balancer service as well or is it just the host and part and it can be anything after that ? @HarshManvar

Comment: It can be anything no need to do anything